# Python - write/ADD a new record in file with Json format

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

I want to add a new record at the end of my file Json, For now it contains

```
 {
    "1":
         { 
           "coef":987,
           "Term":
              {
                 "x1":6,"x2":0,"x3":8
              }
          }
  }
```

im reading this file like this :

```
  try:
      json_data=open ("/home/sage/content.txt")
      data=json.load (json_data)
  except IOError:
   print "Can't open your file"
```

how to add a new record at the end of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the data , you can't add to the file, you need to create a new file (with the same name if you want):

```
 data['added_data'] = 'some data added'
 write_file = open("/home/sage/content.txt", "w")
 write_file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: he is using `json.load` not `json.loads` otherwise answer is correct +1

Comment: ok thank you ;) but i don't need to add .read() , to read data , it works with json_data=open ("/home/sage/content.txt")

Answer (score 3):

If you are using python 2.5 or newer you should use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement dealing with files:

```
import json

with open('content.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data["2"] = { 
       "coef":987,
       "Term":
          {
             "x1":6,"x2":0,"x3":8
          }
      }

with open('content.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```